How to create S3 Batch Operations job invoking Lambda - "request invalid"
I am try to create a S3 Batch Operations job that invokes a Lambda for each file in my manifest.
I am using boto3 in Python with boto3-stubs type defs to try and help ensure I am making valid calls.
But every attempt I have made to create a job results in a generic error:

botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (InvalidRequest) when calling the CreateJob operation: Request invalid

I have dropped into debugger and stepped through to see if I could glean any more details, but it looks like botocore has no more information to give, it just receives a 400 status response from the AWS API with content of:
<ErrorResponse>
    <Error>
        <Code>InvalidRequest</Code>
        <Message>Request invalid</Message>
    </Error>
    <RequestId>JQ34XHPX26HAEWQV</RequestId>
    <HostId>FQW05eUMJqZNZ94/5Gy+PN/R37AArKSVZy7bvSKIKp9UH1quKuer/XqtpdbsQV3d55vTIgLHipX0uzlPH1jIRw==</HostId>
</ErrorResponse>

This seems like very poor design of the backend service (and/or client lib for not validating the request properly before sending it).
It makes debugging the issue incredibly difficult - am I missing a field? passing a wrong value for a field? something else ...problem with RoleArn permissions? manifest format?
It could be nearly anything. And I don't think there's any logs anywhere I can look at?
The request body is very complicated with dozens of nested fields.
Like I said, I'm using boto3-stubs and all the various requests I have tried are compliant with the type defs in terms of required fields and literal values etc.
There are some existing questions from people with similar problems:

Can't create S3 batch job through boto3 - gets request invalid
Amazon S3 batch job through boto3 - request invalid

Neither of them have accepted answers, I assume were never solved.
In answers there are a couple of recurring suggestions:

use correct literal values S3BatchOperations_CSV_20180820 for manifest spec format and Report_CSV_20180820 for the report format
send a ClientRequestToken string value

But I am doing those already.
My code looks like:
        result = s3control.create_job(
            Description="Manually triggered job to convert parquet files to csv.",
            AccountId=account_id,
            Operation={
                "LambdaInvoke": {
                    "FunctionArn": stack_args.lambda_arn,
                },
            },
            ConfirmationRequired=False,
            Priority=1,
            Report={
                "Bucket": bucket,
                "Format": "Report_CSV_20180820",
                "Enabled": True,
                "Prefix": prefix,
                "ReportScope": "FailedTasksOnly",
            },
            ClientRequestToken=str(uuid4()),
            Manifest={
                "Spec": {
                    "Format": "S3BatchOperations_CSV_20180820",
                    "Fields": ["Bucket", "Key"],
                },
                "Location": {
                    "ObjectArn": manifest_arn,
                    "ETag": manifest_etag,
                },
            },
            Tags=[
                {"Key": "App", "Value": "My App"},
                {"Key": "Environment", "Value": environment},
            ],
            RoleArn=stack_args.invocation_role_arn,
        )

The traceback:
    result = s3control.create_job(
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/anentropic/dev/myproject/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 565, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/anentropic/dev/myproject/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 1022, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (InvalidRequest) when calling the CreateJob operation: Request invalid


Where is this code running? Are you testing it in your machine or in the cloud directly? If this error occurs in the cloud, does the host running the script posses an IAM role with enough permissions to kickstart a batch operation job? could you share the IAM role here if possible?

Which line of code is giving you the InvalidRequest error?

This is running on my machine, so I have done an aws sso login etc beforehand. Earlier parts of the code in this script already list objects in the S3 bucket and put object to store the csv manifest back to the bucket. The line of code that gives the error is just the s3control.create_job call.

I tried creating a job via the AWS web UI instead... this worked so I think that confirms that the RoleArn is assumable and has the right permissions, and that the manifest is valid. The only obvious difference was that the manually launched job required confirmation

Parts I am a bit suspicious about: manifest_etag is derived from a head object query on the S3 bucket, and the value returned by S3 is for some reason a JSON string i.e. '"<etag value>"' ... I read here that this is correct and expected. However when I created it via the web UI the ETag was displayed without its JSON quotes.

deserializing the ETag to a plain string didn't help

After tediously trying many combinations to narrow down the location of the problem I found it is something in my Report arg.
Sending:
            Report={
                "Enabled": False,
            },

...successfully created a job.
Having a closer look at the docs for the individual fields within that structure I can see that Report.Bucket should be the ARN of the bucket and not the bucket name.
By amending my original code to "Bucket": f"arn:aws:s3:::{bucket}", I was now able to create a job.
Several things were quite frustrating here:

Complete lack of useful error feedback from the AWS API
Inconsistent parameter naming... other params that require an ARN are named like FunctionArn, ObjectArn, RoleArn but this param was just called Bucket
Bucket names are globally unique anyway, so why require an ARN? Again it's inconsistent - e.g. the manifest file expects the bucket name as its first column, rather than ARN.

